# user processing not responding because of too many syscalls

Tags: c, linux-kernel

We are designing a user process which has following requirements

1. respond to heartbeat every 6 secs.
2. processing incoming requests & make multiple system calls based on request. 
   In worst case one request can cause about 1000 system calls. (usually a for loop going till 1k)

These syscalls are like getter functions, they are not modifying any DS. 
problem I am facing is that, due to too many system calls, user process is missing heartbeats. 
Multithreading user process is not an option for me. 
Am considering batching these syscalls, but how do arrive at the magic number ?

is mapping kernel memory to user space is valid option ?, not sure if that can be done. 
Appreciate the help. thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly is your process messing with kernel space anyway? Each syscall means a context switch which is expensive. There's probably a much better way to do what you intend without being so heavy on context switches.

Comment: Please tell us more about your process. It sounds like you are polling constantly, rather than having (for instance) something wake your process when something changes; could this be done by child processes with pipes? Could you simply check for incoming requests periodically between the (unidentified) system calls?

Comment: you can use alarms in case processing is not a priority. set up an alarm and in signal handler you can again set the alarm to ring back after 6 sec.

Comment: Its a KVM kernel, we have a ports management infra in kernel, which we poll regularly. So the infra is already thr. 
we need to improve the system performance, hence we are trying to reduce ioctl calls. 

About the user process, it take some configs & pushes to the kernel to kernel has equivalent calls to bring up port, apply config that sort of things.